# need to setup script level logging in robotium

Tags: android, logback, robotium

I am trying to setup logging in my test script (for whatever reasons) like:

```
Logger loggervariable = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestRobotium.class);
solo1.clickOnButton("7");
loggervariable.info("clicked on button 7");
```

I have used log4j while working with Java and it seems to work fine, but not with android/robotium.
I have used slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar and logback-android-1.0.10-2.jar.
the script is working fine but no logs are generated in a file at desired location. The config file settings :

```
<configuration>
   <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <!-- "application-name" is a variable -->
    <File>f:/Logger/test.log</File>
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
     <Pattern>%d %p %t %c - %m%n</Pattern>
    </layout>
   </appender>
   <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
   </root>
</configuration>
```

What i want to achieve is to input/send all text in a log file on disk.(the way we use System.out.Println to send text on console, in this case i want to send it to a file).
i have tried putting the config file in classpath but that didn't seen to help either.
Any help regarding this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try  to give simple file name as <File>test.log</File> .

Comment: Did any of these answered your question?

Comment: I have tried giving simple name, unfortunately it didn't worked out for me.
i am getting the logs in the logcat, using microlog4android i am able to  write to the sdcard but not to the file on system.

Comment: Is there something simpler library/way to use/configure as the logs would be large in my case??

Answer (score 0):

I did it using dynamic configuration using LoggerContext.

```
LoggerContext lc = (LoggerContext)LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
PatternLayoutEncoder encoder1 = new PatternLayoutEncoder();
encoder1.setContext(lc);
encoder1.setPattern(messageFormat);
encoder1.start();

FileAppender<ILoggingEvent> appender = new FileAppender<ILoggingEvent>();
appender.setContext(lc);
String logFileName = context.getDir(DEFAULT_LOGDIR, DEFAULT_LOGDIR_MODE).getAbsolutePath() + "/test.log" ;
appender.setFile(logFileName);
appender.setEncoder(encoder1);

appender.start() ;
```